# Seeding - Laravel Model Factories with 3 level relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently building a system to manage my rental properties. I have a model that holds the properties, and each property can have many leases.

In order to bill the leases, I have a model called `Invoice` which belongs to a `Lease`. Further, an invoice will have many `InvoiceLine`

```
//Property.php
public function leases()
{
        return $this->hasMany(Lease::class);
}

//Lease.php
public function invoices(){
        return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class);
}

//Invoice.php
public function lines()
{
        return $this->hasMany(InvoiceLine::class);
}
```

I am trying to set up seeding for this setup:

```
Property::factory()
   ->count(1)
   ->has(
   Lease::factory()
      ->count(2)
      ->hasInvoices(1) // Where to create "Invoice Lines"?
   )
   ->create();
```

Now, as you can see, when running this seeding I only create an invoice - but no invoice lines.

How can I seed an invoice **with invoice lines** that belongs to a `Lease`?

For reference, this is how the factory classes looks for Invoice and Invoice Line:

```php
//InvoiceFactory.php
return [
    'tax' => 0,
    'total' => 25000,
];
//InvoiceLineFactory.php
return [
    'description' => 'Rent for April',
    'tax' => 0,
    'total' => 25000,
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `has` instead of `hasInvoices`.

```
Property::factory()->has(
    Lease::factory()->has(
        Invoice::factory()->has(
            InvoiceLine::factory()->count(3),
        )->count(1)
    )->count(2)
)->count(1)->create();
```